# Js files not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

CSS files seem to load properly.
JS files also seem to load, but all of them is inactive, with no error message on the consol.

my files are:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/libs/font-awesome4/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_debug_toolbar/static/css/toolbar.css?0.7082793798424954" type="text/css">
</head>
```

The only file that site-specific is script.js. Script.js is the short code below:

```
$.fn.countdown = function (callback, duration, message) {
    message = message || "";
    var container = $(this[0]).html(duration + message);
    var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        if (--duration) {
            container.html(duration + message);
        } else {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            callback.call(container);   
        }
    }, 1000);
};

// Use p.countdown as container, pass redirect, duration, and optional message
$(".countdown").countdown(submit_on_time, 30, "s remaining");

// Function to be called after 5 seconds
function submit_on_time () {
    $('#interview-form').submit();
}
```

[image]

I am having hard time finding the source of this problem.

Comment: Seems like you forgot `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is in the `<head>` section, before any of the elements are available, so `$(".countdown")` returns an empty object.
You need to add `$(document).ready()` or place the scripts at the bottom, right before `</body>` (or at least below the elements you're trying to access).

```js
$.fn.countdown = function (callback, duration, message) {
    message = message || "";
    var container = $(this[0]).html(duration + message);
    var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        if (--duration) {
            container.html(duration + message);
        } else {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            callback.call(container);   
        }
    }, 1000);
};

// Function to be called after 5 seconds
function submit_on_time () {
    $('#interview-form').submit();
}

// Use p.countdown as container, pass redirect, duration, and optional message

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".countdown").countdown(submit_on_time, 30, "s remaining");
});
```